# Add array to a html file from javascript (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, replace, charts

I have an html file and a javascript file (Google Apps Script), and the html file renders a chart.
I want to add an array into that chart from the javascript file but it won't work (so trying this alternative idea).

Here is the html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Position' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows(

      //HERES WHERE I WANT TO ADD IN THE ARRAY THAT FUNCTIONS PROPERLY

    );
    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }
</script>

<div id="example3.1" style="height: 400px;">Graph D</div>
```

Here is my Code.gs:

```
function showDialog() {//This shows the modal which renders the chart

//Firstly replace the placeholder in the html with the below array somehow. Then...
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('GraphD')
    .setWidth(800)
    .setHeight(700);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}
```

This is the array I want to insert into the html file before rendering:

```
var MyArray = [[ 'President', 'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'President', 'John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'President', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Vice President', 'John Adams', new Date(1789, 3, 21), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Vice President', 'Thomas Jefferson', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
      [ 'Vice President', 'George Clinton', new Date(1805, 2, 4), new Date(1812, 3, 20)]];
```

So I want the above array inserted into the commented placeholder in the HTML before then rendering Any help would be great.

Comment: I’m confused copy paste doesn’t work? (Please forgive me, I’m not trying to be rude)

Comment: In your situation, where is `MyArray`?

Comment: @Tanaike - the dates are being drawn from the CalendarApp into the javascript file variable (var myArray). I've written it there as it would appear once I have it stored. (The dates I've made up for example purposes).

Comment: @evolutionxbox I've written the array there as it appears once I draw it from an API into the javascript and store it in a variable. I need it to dynamically replace the placeholder in the html file - i can't copy and paste.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your script, which is `MyArray` put in the files of `Code.gs` (Google Apps Script) or `GraphD.html` (HTML and Javascript)? I couldn't understand what `the javascript file` in your replying is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to pass an `Array` from Google Apps Script as the argument of `DataTable` method of Google Charts API on the client-side.

One way is to use `google.script.run` to exectute a server-side function to read/generate the data to be visualized on the chart and pass it to the client-side code, but this API cannot pass JavaScript Date objects, so instead of passing these type of objects we should pass some represention of them.

What if instead of passing a JavaScript Array containing Date objects we pass a JSON? The `DataTable` method could supports an Array but also a JSON.

Passing an JSON, allows us to instead of passing `new Date(1789,3,30)` to pass `"Date(1789,3,30)"` (drop `new` and enclose the remaining between quotes characters).

Example:

```js
function showDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"), 
    "My dialog")
}

function doSomething(){
  var data = {
    cols:[
      { type: 'string', id: 'Position' },
      { type: 'string', id: 'Name' },
      { type: 'date', id: 'Start' },
      { type: 'date', id: 'End' }
    ],
    rows:[
      {c:[ {v:"President"}, {v:"George Washington"}, {v:"Date(1789, 3, 30)"}, {v:"Date(1797, 2, 4)"}]},
      {c:[ {v:"President"}, {v:"John Adams"}, {v:"Date(1797, 2, 4)"}, {v:"Date(1801, 2, 4)" }]},
      {c:[ {v:"President"}, {v:"Thomas Jefferson"}, {v:"Date(1801, 2, 4)"}, {v:"Date(1809, 2, 4)" }]},
      {c:[ {v:"Vice President"}, {v:"John Adams"}, {v:"Date(1789, 3, 21)"}, {v:"Date(1797, 2, 4)"}]},
      {c:[ {v:"Vice President"}, {v:"Thomas Jefferson"}, {v:"Date(1797, 2, 4)"}, {v:"Date(1801, 2, 4)"}]},
      {c:[ {v:"Vice President"}, {v:"George Clinton"}, {v:"Date(1805, 2, 4)"}, {v:"Date(1812, 3, 20)"}]}
    ]
  }
    return data;
}
```

index.html

```html
<div id="example3.1" style="height: 400px;">Graph D</div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script>
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data){
      var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
      var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
      var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);
      chart.draw(dataTable);
   }).doSomething();
  }
</script>
```

Resources

- [Date and times | Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes)
- [Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#format-of-the-constructors-javascript-literal-data-parameter)

Comment: Fantastic thank you @Rubén you've been extremely helpful. That's working and I'm succesfully passing in variables to the 'array'. I'm not familiar with that 'literal data' format ("{c:[ {v:" etc) which seems strange but its working. Thanks again.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you very much! 